# Using CSS, I can't make my table of divs centered in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to place two buttons next to each other in the center of the screen, not the center of the webpage. When I attempt to follow instructions I found online to set the margins as I have in my code, it only centers the buttons vertically, not horizontally.

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="onCampusChef.css" />
</head>
<body>
<section id="main1">
    <div id="signUpContainer">
        <table id="signUp">
            <tr>
                <td id="signUpChef" class="signUp"> 
                    <div>
                        <!--sign up for chef location here--> <a href="">Sign up as a chef!</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="signUpClient" class="signUp">
                    <div>
                        <!--sign up for client location here--> <a href="">Sign up as a client!</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="main2">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>**
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
}

#main1 {
    height:110vh;
    width:100%;
    background-image:URL("main1.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}



#signUp {   /*This is the CSS for the table containing the two divs that are the buttons*/
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.signUp {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:20px;
}

#main2 {
    height:100vh;
}



a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

How can I center it properly?

Comment: So you just want [this example](http://jsbin.com/cisuxi/1/edit?html,css,output)? There are a whole bunch of methods. No need for `<table>`

Comment: Yes, but I can't use px for width, because it needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
text-align: center;
```

to one of the surrounding divs. This solved a similar issue I faced on my site.

Comment: Added it to the #signup, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help's you in the class i think it was signup inside it just add `text-align: center;`

Now your code should look like

```
#signUp {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It just placed the boxes at the top left.

Comment: Then try by setting height of your html and body tag at 100% and if not then set table or div height to 100%

Answer (score 0):

### HTML Diet

Let's strip your HTML:

```
<section id="main1">           
     <a href="">Sign up as a chef!</a>
     <a href="">Sign up as a client!</a>                 
</section>
```

Much better!

### Sprinkle of CSS

The section is vertically centered with `position: absolute` and the combination of left, right, top, bottom and `margin: auto`.

```css
#main1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1em;
}
#main1 a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e91e63;
}
```

#### Complete Example

```css
#main1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1em;
}
#main1 a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #e91e63;
}
```

```html
<section id="main1">

  <a href="">Sign up as a chef!</a><a href="">Sign up as a client!</a>

</section>
```

Comment: But the table isn't centered in the middle of the page, just the middle at the top.

Comment: Haha I thought thats what you didnt want. I'll change.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML File**

```
<div id="signUpContainer">
     <div id='signUp' class='signUp'>
           <a href="">Sign up as a chef!</a>
     </div>
     <div id='signUp' class='signUp'>
           <a href="">Sign up as a client!</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS File**

```
#signUpContainer {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#signUp {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Try it yourself and edit to your likings. What i basically did was i styled on a div instead of a table (in your example).

Comment: This is really close, but it makes the 2 divs on top of each other, instead of side-by-side. It only makes them side-by-side at full screen, and it needs to be responsive.

Comment: Try and adjust the width in #signUp. You can use em or percentage.